# In our phone English class vs on our phone English class

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

1. > I will answer that question in our phone English class.
2. > I will answer that question on our phone English class.
3. > I will answer that question in our on-the-phone English class.

Which is correct?  I know we should say "in" if it's "in our class" and "on" if it's "on the phone".  But what if it is a phone English class?

Comment: better use 'tele'. It looks professional! Phone English Class, at least in India, I've never heard of! :(

Answer (score 1):

"Phone" is modifying "English class", so you say it the same way as if there was just "class": "in our phone English class" (or "in our on-the-phone English class" if it's not immediately clear that your class is being held over the phone).

When you answer a question *on* something, it's the same as answering a question *about* that. But answering a question *in* a class is the same as answering it *during* that class. Those don't change.